# publish as a page admin using SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using latest version of Facebook's PHP SDK.I have e page where I am only admin. I tried to post page update using Graph api. Here is my code:

```
//index.php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => $log_json['app_id'],
    'app_secret' => $log_json['app_secret'],
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['manage_pages', 'pages_show_list', 'publish_pages'];
$callback = 'http://localhost:8000/return.php';
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);

echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

and the last part:

```
//return.php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => $log_json['app_id'],
    'app_secret' => $log_json['app_secret'],
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();  //for long lived access token

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // There was an error communicating with Graph
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
if (isset($accessToken)) {
    $longAccessToken = $client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
    DB::saveLongLivedToken($longAccessToken); //save token to database
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = DB::getLongLivedToken();
    //dump($response);
    $res = $fb->post('<page id>/feed', array('message' => 'Hello'), $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    dump($res); 
    exit;
} elseif ($helper->getError()) {
 ....
    exit;
}
```

But when the return.php tried to call the api it throws an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' in.............
```

Comment: debug your access token and make sure it includes publish_pages: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: yes it includes publish_pages scope.

Comment: Are you using the pages access token? Doesn't seem like it.